# Weekly chat session topic ideas

Tags: discussion, chat

Our weekly chat sessions seem to be getting *slightly* more people in the last few weeks. Since people ask for topics from time to time, here's a place where people can brainstorm on ideas. Something easy to summarize in a short sentence, please.

Chat topics do not need to be anything like a Stack Exchange question; anything goes, let's just keep the ideas related to writing somehow. You can be silly, or serious, or a little of both if you like.

Let's see those fertile imaginations!

Edit: Here's the [current schedule of events in our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/168/the-overlook-hotel?tab=schedule).

Comment: I'd just like to say I'd like to see topics that provoke _discussion_, more than a round-robin of opinions. Not even necessarily writing-related - anything that gets us talking and getting to know each other a bit better would be really nice :)

Comment: hey, when is this chat?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - Currently mondays at 1pm EST.

Answer (score 4):

What fiction do you like to read for pleasure?

Bonus points for introducing cool stuff other people don't already know.

Comment: Any chance to tell you all what I like sounds good to me, that's my favorite subject.

Answer (score 2):

- How to get to know your characters?  How does everybody else do this? How do you know when you're ready to write them?

Answer (score 2):

Music while writing: Yes or no? Why?

Answer (score 2):

What's your "throw across the room" book? (the book that you started reading and then threw it across the room, shouting, "*I* could write better than this!")

Comment: I -so- have one of these. It was unreadable garbage and I have no idea to this day how it ever made it into print, let alone a movie.

Comment: Eragon or Twilight? :)